# Spin off another container on host machine from an existing container

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac, docker-desktop

I am currently using **Docker Desktop for Mac**.

My requirement is to *spin off a container from another container*.

**Situation**:

Container A has a service running which upon request looks for a swarm manager and spin off another container B. I have started single node swarm manager on my machine. I can not use host network_mode because docker for MAC exposes light weight linux vm as host and not my actual localhost. I have tried this also : https://forums.docker.com/t/access-host-not-vm-from-inside-container/11747/7

Any possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that your container can access your host. So, use the [Engine API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/) provided by Docker:

```
POST /containers/create
```

You will have to post json that contains the details of the new container.

> **Engine API v1.24**
>
> The daemon listens on `unix:///var/run/docker.sock` but you can [Bind Docker to another host/port or a Unix socket](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#bind-docker-to-another-host-port-or-a-unix-socket).
>
> You can listen on port 2375 on all network interfaces with `-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375`, or on a particular network interface using its IP address: `-H tcp://192.168.59.103:2375`. It is conventional to use port 2375 for un-encrypted, and port 2376 for encrypted communication with the daemon.

Comment: In case of port forwarding your solution works, but in case of "host" networking mode we can't know the Hyperkit VM's IP ( which docker for MAC uses) to use docker API.